# Origin of the English word chevel

Tags: meaning, etymology, verbs

I'm originally from Yorkshire and my family, especially my mum, used the verb 'chevel', in the context of "you're always cheveling sweets". I don't know what the exact spelling was. Does anyone know its origins? Her family originated from the northeast coast of England, Saltburn to Scarborough.

I'm new to this forum so have just realised the question became closed. The word was used to describe me 'chewing' sweets.

Comment: Sure it wasn't "shovelling"?

Comment: What does the word mean?

Comment: Were you *coaxing for more*, *stealing*, *begging for*, or *stuffing* sweets? If you were *coaxing* sweets from your mother, the word might be *wheedle*.

Comment: It sounds like the Lancashire dialect _chewin'_.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your replies. My Mum was always a very precise speaker so I'm pretty sure it was 'chevel' and not 'shovel' or 'chivel' or anything else sounding similar. She also did say "cheveling at sweets" as well as "cheveling sweets", so it may have come from chisel I suppose. It was always said to me when she saw me chewing the sweets so I took it to mean 'chewing at' or 'stuffing' myself with them. Because of where she herself originated (North East coast of England) I'm aware of the huge Viking influence there and wondered if there was any link with the Old Norse language.

Comment: @Stephanie - wow, this is a word I haven't heard for years. It was a word my mother used too, though I remember it being more of a 'chavel' sound rather than 'chevel'. But the meaning was definitely the same - eating, gnawing away at something. My mother always used it when the dog was grooming herself - 'Stop chavelling!'. I've searched for this, and apparently it means 'to chew', and comes from the ME chavel (which gave us the word 'jowl'). If you do a search for 'chavellling Yorkshire', you should find a link to a PhD thesis from 1952 by Albert Lyon Hoy. Chavel is on p 93.

Comment: Why has this question been closed? It seems clear to me what it was asking, and I can/could provide a full answer for it.

Comment: @Kiloran_speaking It was closed because more details were required; your comment is a good answer following the provision of more detail: please do answer now the question is reopened. Stephanie, please [edit] your question to provide all the information which would help **within the question itself.** Thank you.

Comment: @Andrew Leach: Thank you! I've posted an answer now.

Answer (score 6):

I'm also from Yorkshire, and this was a word my mother used too. I think the word you're looking for is '**chavel**' rather then 'chevel'. The meaning is definitely the same - chewing, gnawing away at something. My mother always used it when the dog was grooming herself - 'Stop chavelling!'.

According to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chavel) it means 'nibble, gnaw' and comes from the Middle English 'chavlen, chaulen', and Old English 'ceafl' (meaning 'cheek or jowl').

[Definitions](https://www.definitions.net/definition/chavel) says that 'to chavel' means 'to chew'. The same site says that it's also a noun, meaning:

> The jaw, especially, the jaw of a beast

I found a very interesting PhD thesis from 1952 by Albert Lyon Hoy, which gives an etymological glossary of the East Yorkshire dialect. [This link](https://d.lib.msu.edu/etd/5121/datastream/OBJ/download/An_etymological_glossary_of_the_East_Yorkshire_dialect.pdf) will open a PDF of his thesis: 'chavel' is on pg 93.

Loy found a couple of examples of the word in Old/Middle English texts, in [The Owl and the Nightingale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Owl_and_the_Nightingale), line 284 and in [Ancrene Wisse](https://www.bl.uk/collection-items/ancrene-wisse#), line 70.

Loy also found a definition in an old publication:

> 'Chawle, to chew imperfectly' (from *A Glossary of Words Used in
> Holderness in the East-Riding of Yorkshire*, published by the English
> Dialect Society in 1977)

Answer (score 2):

I can't find this word, but I've found some suggestive similar terms.

There is dialect word further south *chivel* meaning to chip away at, tear, crumble into pieces (J Wright, [*The English Dialect Dictionary*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=SNARAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA592&ots=vB65dyoNgo&dq=chivel%20dialect&pg=PA592#v=onepage&q=chivel%20dialect&f=false), 1898), and *chibble* with a similar meaning, with *chibbles* used for small pieces of food in various parts of central and southern England ([Word Detective](http://www.word-detective.com/2010/04/chibbles/)).

This may be related to the verb *chisel* which literally means to carve away at with a [chisel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chisel) but in slang means "to employ shrewd or unfair practices on in order to obtain one's end" ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chisel)).

There's a Romany (Gypsy) word [chorav](https://en.glosbe.com/rom/en/chorav) which means steal. It's gone into the Scots language as [chore, char or chorey](https://dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/chore_v) (from *Scottish National Dictionary (1700–)* and [supplement](https://dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/sndns812)). There is commonality between Scots and dialects of northeast England, as well as lots of words from Romany passed directly into English slang. Another corruption of this word might give "chever" or "chevel".

It might help if you provide more information on what exactly it means.

Comment: Bizarrely, when my Mum was a child her Mum (my Grandmother) always let Roamny Gypsies camp in the bottom of their garden for year upon year during the summer. It could indeed be something she picked up from the Romamy Gypsies, great shout, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is very interesting.

The Oxford English Dictionary entry for ***jowl*** meaning a jawbone, carries the following etymology - which includes the Middle English word ***chevel***.

> *Forms:  α. Old English ceafl, (? ceáfl), Middle English cheafl, chefl,
> chæfl, (? chouel), Middle English chauel, chavel, cheuel, **chevel**,
> Middle English chawl, chaul, Middle English chavyl(l, Middle
> English–1600s chaule, Middle English chawylle, 1500s chall(e, Middle
> English–1600s chawle; 1800s dialect chole. β. 1500s–1600s ioule, 1600s
> jowle, joll, 1800s jole, jowl.*

The word ***chew*** also includes ***chewen*** in its Middle English etymology.

All these words would seem to come from the same Old High German root. I had not heard ***chevel*** before - though I'm also a native of the east coast - namely Norfolk.

Though the Norfolk dialect, sometimes appearing in sympathy with the east coast (see the entry on "staithe") generally, has clearer linguistic links to the south of England.